# Union view losing records

Tags: mysql, database, union

## Problem

I am losing records when executing query in view.

## Regular query

```
SELECT `COUNTRY`, COUNT(`COUNTRY`) from chile.tablechile
UNION SELECT `COUNTRY`, COUNT(`COUNTRY`) from costarica.tablecostarica
UNION SELECT `COUNTRY`, COUNT(`COUNTRY`) from elsalvador.tableelsalvador
UNION SELECT `COUNTRY`, COUNT(`COUNTRY`) from guatemala.tableguatemala
```

### value counts

| COUNTRY | COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| CHILE | 5488892 |
| COSTA RICA | 952113 |
| EL SALVADOR | 1346861 |
| GUATEMALA | 2744655 |

## View

```
CREATE VIEW `new_view` AS
SELECT `COUNTRY`, `COL1`, `COL2`, `COL3` from chile.flotachile
UNION SELECT `COUNTRY`, `COL1`, `COL2`, `COL3` from costarica.flotacostarica
UNION SELECT `COUNTRY`, `COL1`, `COL2`, `COL3` from elsalvador.flotaelsalvador
UNION SELECT `COUNTRY`, `COL1`, `COL2`, `COL3` from guatemala.flotaguatemala;

SELECT `COUNTRY`, COUNT(`COUNTRY`)
FROM view_database.new_view
GROUP BY `COUNTRY`
;
```

### value counts

| COUNTRY | COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| CHILE | 349638 |
| COSTA RICA | 61707 |
| EL SALVADOR | 51902 |
| GUATEMALA | 348985 |

Comment: Union comes with free dedupe/distinct you should use union all. AND I don't see what you gain by having a view.

Comment: I guess you don't need us to tell you that your schema is distinctly odd.

Comment: @Strawberry oh boy, you have no idea. My client has the Excel mindset (30 columns, millons rows) and now is asking me to visualize in a single PowerBI. And can't create a proper scheme because time restrictions.

Comment: @P.Salmon Thank you for your answer, i will try UNION ALL. What do i gain? I need to visualize all data in a single PowerBI and i am trying to get a single table to use as source. All data is in multiple databases and Power can only conect with one.

Answer (score 0):

Be wary of distinct implicit in union for example

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
CREATE TABLE T
(ID INT,ORDER_NUM INT, STATUS INT);
INSERT INTO T VALUES
(1,100,1),(1,100,1),(1,300,2);

select t.* from t
union
select t.* from t;

+------+-----------+--------+
| ID   | ORDER_NUM | STATUS |
+------+-----------+--------+
|    1 |       100 |      1 |
|    1 |       300 |      2 |
+------+-----------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.002 sec)
```

whereas

```
select t.* from t
union all
select t.* from t;

+------+-----------+--------+
| ID   | ORDER_NUM | STATUS |
+------+-----------+--------+
|    1 |       100 |      1 |
|    1 |       100 |      1 |
|    1 |       300 |      2 |
|    1 |       100 |      1 |
|    1 |       100 |      1 |
|    1 |       300 |      2 |
+------+-----------+--------+
6 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

If this is not the issue then publish sample data